# A sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

Let $n \ge k \ge 1$ be integers. What is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{2(k-i)} \left( n-i \atop k-i \right)
\left( 2i-1 \atop i \right) 
$$
in terms of $n$ and $k$? I am trying to find a closed form of this integer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a closed form, only noted some relations (which maybe can be shown via induction). Let $p(n,k)$ be the sum you have, where $n \ge k \ge 1.$ Then (numerically up to $n=10$ at least) the relation
$$p(n+1,k)=p(n,k)+4p(n,k-1)$$
for $n \ge k \ge 2.$ This would allow one to recurse "down the columns" as long as each columnn heading $p(n,n)$ was known. For $n=1,2,3 \cdots$ these begin $1,7,38,187,874,3958,17548,\cdots.$

I found the latter in o.e.i.s as A000531. [If you google o.e.i.s. and go to the page, you can enter the above A000531 at the prompt, or else several initial terms as above.]